# Cannot convert string to float - Not a Number (NaN)

Tags: angular, nan

```
I need to convert string to float to summarize all numbers and get the average.

I have tried Number(), parseFloat none of them are giving me the expected output.
```

For example instead of return 2 it is returning ‘11’

I am colleting data from this API: https://www.hatchways.io/api/assessment/students
obs(to retrieve the data, I created a service:
export class StudentsService {

studentsUrl: string = "https://www.hatchways.io/api/assessment/students";

constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

//casting observable into Students array
  getAllStudents(): Observable<{students: Students[]}> {
    //return this.http.get(this.studentsUrl);
    return this.http.get<{students: Students[]}>(`${this.studentsUrl}`);
  }
}

```
getAVG() {
for(let i = 0; i < this.students.length; i++) {
      //console.log('Estudante número: '+ i);
      for(let z = 0; z < 8; z++) {
        //console.log('Notas index: ' + z);
        this.grades[i] += Number(this.students[i].grades[z]);
        console.log('nota: '+ this.students[i].grades[z]);
      }
      var num = parseFloat(this.grades[0]);
      console.log('#######sum das notas######: ' + num);
    }
}

I need to sum all grades in the array to calculate the average and display it
```

Comment: Can you specify what you mean by "none of them have worked"?

Comment: I was trying to say that Number() and parseFloat() have not worked.

Comment: Do not give me the expected output. For example: instead of 2 I am getting 11

Comment: @Henry i am not getting the expected output. For example instead of 2 I am getting 11

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are on the right track with `parseFloat()` (`parseInt()` in this case would also work), it's just a matter of using it right.

You essentially want to go through each `grade` of the `student.grades` array and add its value to a sum that you'll later divide but the number of grades.

Something like this

```
this.students.forEach(student =>
{
    let sum = 0;
    student.grades.forEach(grade=>sum+=parseFloat(grade))  //Goes through each grade, parses it as float and add it's result to sum
    let avg = sum/student.grades.length;
})
```

***Note***: I'm using forEach to iterate through arrays, but using a regular for loop is fine as well. It's just a matter of preference here

There are other ways to get sum/average (array.reduce is one of them), but as long as you parse your string, anything is fine.

[Here's a working Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-http-service-16j4bb) of your scenario to illustrate.

If you have any questions let me know

Answer (score 0):

you have to initialize `this.grades[i]=0;` before you begin second loop(one with 'z).

```
for(let i = 0; i < this.students.length; i++) {
  //console.log('Estudante número: '+ i);

  this.grades[i]=0;

  for(let z = 0; z < 8; z++) {
    //console.log('Notas index: ' + z);
    this.grades[i] += Number(this.students[i].grades[z]);
    console.log('nota: '+ this.students[i].grades[z]);
  }
  var num = parseFloat(this.grades[0]);
  console.log('#######sum das notas######: ' + num);
}
```

}

Comment: if u want each students total grades in 'this.grades' array for later purpose u can do it like this, otherwise @Jojofoulk 's way is more simpler.